# Can't access module object properties from main in Screeps

Tags: javascript, screeps

I have the following simple test module (called `testModule`) in [Screeps](http://www.screeps.com):

```
module.Exports = {
    myProperty:'test'
};
```

In `main`, I try to output the contents of the module like so:

```
var x = require('testModule');
console.log("Value:" + JSON.stringify(x));
```

But all I get is an empty object (`{}`);

As a result, `x.myProperty` is undefined.  I have also tried making the module into a function, like so:

```
module.Exports = function(){
    return {
        myProperty:'test'
    };
};
```

Then assigning it to `x` with `var x = require('testModule')();` but I get the same result.

Obviously the game is still in development, so it is possible that this is a bug, but I'd like to rule out a mistake on my part first.  Anyone been able to achieve what I'm trying to do?  Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**

Interestingly, it gives me the same empty object even if I change the module to this:

```
module.Exports = 'test';
```

Surely this should be printing the string `'test'` rather than an empty object?  Is this a quirk of require js?

Answer (score 3):

Just figured this out - I was using an uppercase E in `module.exports`.  I have corrected the case and now it works fine:

```
module.exports = {
    myProperty:'test'
};
```